# node js file systems read a dynamically changing path to a pdf

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid

I am trying to **read a pdf file** from fs and send it through email using sendgrid.
My folder structure is like this

```
/
-src
 --controllers
   ---travelplan.js
-pdf
```

In the **travelplan.js** if I do it like this

```
fs.readFile('pdf/204.pdf', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
           console.log("THIS ERROR IS AWESOME", err)
        }
})
```

everything works fine. No problem.

But if read it like this

```
let pdf_number = 204;

fs.readFile(`pdf/${pdf_number}.pdf`, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
           console.log("THIS ERROR IS AWESOME", err)
        }
})
```

This doesn't work. Pdf doesn't send correctly.

Then I tried this

```
let pdf_number = 204;

var pdf_path = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'pdf',pdf_number);

fs.readFile(pdf_path, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
           console.log("THIS ERROR IS AWESOME", err)
        }
})
```

This also doesn't work.

How do I read a pdf file by passing the pdf file name as an argument?

Comment: Apparently, you might be getting the path of your file wrong as this should work. Just to be sure, I've tested on my machine using a number to try to red a file named `2.txt` and it worked. I'm saying that because, in your couple of examples, you were tring to get the file at `${__dirname}/pdf/204.pdf` and, at the last one, you tried to retrieve it from `${__dirname}/../pdf/204.pdf`. Do you care to share your folder structure?

Comment: My bad. Did not notice the structure at the question. Well, you should be able to read the pdf files by adding a `../`before the `pdf/`. The safer option would be to use `__dirname` because when you execute a script via `node`, it will se your current working directory as the starting point. You could do something like `const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, \`../pdf/${pdf_number}.pdf\`);`. It worked for me.

Comment: @GabrielCosta `First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.` I got this error after I try.

Comment: According to the documentation ( https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths ), it should be fine to call `path.resolve` with multiple arguments. This error most likely be happening somewhere else. How are you executing the file?

Comment: @GabrielCosta yes your correct. My real problem was something else. I've created a new question for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996074/nodejs-file-systems-wait-to-resolve-until-the-file-successfully-created